# How do I add these arguments to netbeans run.xml file for a project?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am going from this batch file

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.3\bin\java.exe" -cp bin;lib/clientlibs.jar client 0 live english game0
pause
```

to run.xml in netbeans and I keep getting this error:

> ```
> Bad argument count, Usage: worldid, <live/rc/wip>, <english/german>, <game0/game1>
> C:\Users\aaron\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
> ```

I've tried resolving the arguments but I can't figure out how this run.xml file works. Really trying to get this one figured out.

I expect the project to load the client but it won't because of "bad arguments"

Comment: I was able to add the arguments to the project and get the project to run in netbeans, but I get the same error when I try to run the project directly from the main file, or when I jar the file

Comment: How do I add these arguments to run.xml for netbeans

Comment: I even got the plugin so I can run the client.java file with arugments, but how do I compile the .jar with the arguments?